# distribute option in interface builder of iPhone

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

i have following buttons in my application.

Now i want to set equal spacing among all buttons.

Suppose If I am using corelDraw or Photoshop, there is always an option for align & distribute.

Here I need to distribute my objects vertically.

How is that possible in interface builder of iPhone?

Sample image is given below, in which distribution is required.
[alt text http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/4146/problem13.png](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/4146/problem13.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of object, you might do this.

```
Select all implied objects. 

Select Editor->Embed in->Matrix;
```

this will place the objects regularly.

```
Then select the option Editor->Unembed
```

and the objects will keep their new positions. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is ages ago, but for the sake of simplicity (maybe) and to avoid using table views (for sure)...

In your example, if you select the first UIButton, keyword, and press option key, interface builder shows you the relative distance from the center to any other object you hover with the mouse. So if you decide the optimal distance is the one between keyword and category buttons, you can apply that distance for the rest of objects simply adding or substracting the appropriate amount of pixels from the button size inspector.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there an option to do it automatically, you can do some math though and get them to have equal spacing by setting their frames...

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to place all of these in a table (since they look like table view cells anyway), and adjust an empty footer view height to get the spacing you want between elements.

Of course that means you don't get to view the layout in IB.

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler - Simply drag a "Flexible Space Bar Button Item" from the Object Library in Xcode into each gap. It will automatically expand to equispace your other items.

&